# Do I need to create a separate IAP for every iOS newsstand issue?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, in-app-purchase, newsstand-kit

I need to support the purchase of single issues within an iOS newsstand app (and not just a free or paid subscription).

Do I need to manually create a new IAP in iTunesConnect for every single issue, or can I somehow automate this (as with the [atom feed](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/NewsstandAtomFeedSpecification.pdf) for Newsstand metadata like issue cover URL, title, summary etc.))?

Follow-up question: If it's not a newsstand app, would that make things easier/worse (to support purchasing single issues)? How do other "normal" apps handle the frequent addition of new paid content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own questions, summarizing some threads on the Apple developer forums:

- Yes, if you want to sell individual issues, you must have a (non-consumable) IAP set up for each.
- Last fall, "Transporter" was added to iTunesConnect to allow upload and management of IAPs from the command line. See [WWDC12 slides](http://adcdownload.apple.com//wwdc_2012/wwdc_2012_session_pdfs/session_305__whats_new_in_itunes_connect_for_app_developers.pdf). You can find the user guide and the XML spec at the bottom of the "Manage your applications" page in ITC.

Comment: [Here’s a public repo](https://gist.github.com/lexrus/5792296) with all WWDC 2013 session videos, including #305 which also covers this matter.